# Simply script using substr to increment IDs

Tags: jquery, loops, substr

I have the following code which contains 20 code blocks. They are all the same excepting the ID number for each. I tried looking how to simplify the code pasted below using substr. Can someone please explain if this is posible and offer an example.

```
$( "#ep1box" ).on('mouseover focusin' , function() {
  $('#episode-1__heading-text').css('text-decoration','underline');
  $('#episode-1__heading-number').css('color','#fff');
});

$( "#ep1box" ).on('mouseleave focusout' , function() {
  $('#episode-1__heading-text').css('text-decoration','none');
  $('#episode-1__heading-number').css('color','#18be91');
});
$( "#ep2box" ).on('mouseover focusin' , function() {
  $('#episode-2__heading-text').css('text-decoration','underline');
  $('#episode-2__heading-number').css('color','#fff');
});

$( "#ep2box" ).on('mouseleave focusout' , function() {
  $('#episode-2__heading-text').css('text-decoration','none');
  $('#episode-2__heading-number').css('color','#c428ff');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use substr because what you're trying to do is build a string. Just put it together with +:

```
for(i=0; i < 20; i++) {
  $( "#ep" + i + "box" ).on('mouseover focusin' , function() {
    $('#episode-' + i + '__heading-text').css('text-decoration','underline');
    $('#episode-' + i + '__heading-number').css('color','#fff');
  });

  $( "#ep" + i + "box" ).on('mouseleave focusout' , function() {
    $('#episode-' + i + '__heading-text').css('text-decoration','none');
    $('#episode-' + i + '__heading-number').css('color','#18be91');
  });
}
```

Of course, it would make things much more straightforward if you could just give them all a specific class to denote that they have something in common. Then you don't need a loop at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer James. Sory for the delay in answering I was on my annual holiday, lucky me.